# Angular returning it's own tags instead of output in ejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I tried doing some input validation on my inputs at my ejs template using angular, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, this is the code i used (from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_validate_required)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="">

<p>Try writing in the input field:</p>

<form name="myForm">
<input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
</form>

<p>The input's valid state is:</p>
<h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

It's supposed to ouput something like this:

```
The input's valid state is: false
```

But instead it just returns this:

```
The input's valid state is: {{myForm.myInput.$valid}}
```

So is it in any way possible to use ejs and angular together?

Comment: Please make your title a question or at least related to the question itself **without** including the technologies used as those are in the tags already.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, that's been done :)

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a module and a controller defined, script should be loaded inside the body/head

**HTML**

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="store">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="">
        <form name="myForm">
          <input name="myInput" ng-model="myInput" required>
        </form>
        <p>The input's valid state is:</p>
        <h1>{{myForm.myInput.$valid}}</h1>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**Controller**

```
 var app = angular.module('store', []);
 app.controller('StoreController', function($scope) {

 });
```

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/W1zi8N45H6XKYxXHgqBW?p=preview)

Comment: well, that is quite obvious, should've tried that first. I'll accept once i can :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<html ng-app="insert_app_name_here">

<body ng-controller="insert_controller_name_here">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would set up my angular app like the above code. Also, including the script at the end of your body tag is good practice. Moreover, removing the `.min` from your script tag to just `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js` helps you debug your code better since you will be using it for development and not for production.

In setting up your app, I would include an `app.js` file where the code goes like this:

```
angular.module('insert_app_name_here', [])
```

In setting up your controller, I would include a controller file (i.e. `mainCtrl.js`) where the code goes like this:

```
angular.module('insert_app_name_here').controller('insert_controller_name_here, function($scope) {

});
```

As to linking angular with ejs, i am unfamiliar with ejs, therefore i cannot provide a solution for that.

Comment: thanks for your answer, altough all i needed was module and controller definition.